# How to run nativescript project in another visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

I created android app using native script and i am using visual studio code.
so i want to run same project in another laptop using visual studio code.
so please tell me how to run because whenever i am trying to run project,its not able to build.

here is error:

> E:\NS-APP\sample-ImageUpload-master>tns run android Skipping prepare.
>   Searching for devices... Building project...
>
> > Configuring > 0/3 projects > root project  :config phase:  createDefaultIncludeFiles
> >             +found plugins: nativescript-background-http
> >             +found plugins: nativescript-telerik-ui
> >             +found plugins: tns-core-modules-widgets
>
> :config phase:  createPluginsConfigFile
>            Creating product flavors include.gradle file in E:\NS-APP\sample-ImageUpload-master\platforms\android/configurations
>   folder...
>
> :config phase:  pluginExtend
>           +applying configuration from: E:\NS-APP\sample-ImageUpload-master\platforms\android\configurations\include.gradle
>           +applying configuration from: E:\NS-APP\sample-ImageUpload-master\platforms\android\configurations\nativescript-background-http\include.gradle
>           +applying configuration from: E:\NS-APP\sample-ImageUpload-master\platforms\android\configurations\nativescript-telerik-ui\include.gradle
>           +applying configuration from: E:\NS-APP\sample-ImageUpload-master\platforms\android\configurations\tns-core-modules-widgets\include.gradle
>
> > Configuring > 0/3 projects > root project  :config phase:  addAarDependencies
> >             +adding dependency: E:\NS-APP\sample-ImageUpload-master\platforms\android\libs\aar\Common-2017.1.222-dev-release.aar
> >             +adding dependency: E:\NS-APP\sample-ImageUpload-master\platforms\android\libs\aar\Data-2017.1.222-dev-release.aar
> >             +adding dependency: E:\NS-APP\sample-ImageUpload-master\platforms\android\libs\aar\List-2017.1.222-dev-release.aar
> >             +adding dependency: E:\NS-APP\sample-ImageUpload-master\platforms\android\libs\aar\Primitives-2017.1.222-dev-release.aar
> >             +adding dependency: E:\NS-APP\sample-ImageUpload-master\platforms\android\libs\aar\widgets-release.aar
> >     The JavaCompile.setDependencyCacheDir() method has been deprecated and
> >     is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 4.0. The
> >     TaskInputs.source(Object) method has been deprecated and is scheduled
> >     to be removed in Gradle 4.0. Please use
> >     TaskInputs.file(Object).skipWhenEmpty() instead. Incremental java
> >     compilation is an incubating feature. The Task.leftShift(Closure)
> >     method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle
> >     5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.
> >             at build_1xv9gqucl7v9i0b8ti7pqf8cd.run(E:\NS-APP\sample-ImageUpload-master\platforms\android\build-tools\android-static-binding-generator\build.gradle:126)
> >     :preBuild UP-TO-DATE :preF0F1F2DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> >     :checkF0F1F2DebugManifest :preF0F1F2ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> >     :prepareBackHttpAppRuntimeUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
> >     :prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2531Library UP-TO-DATE
> >     :prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72531Library UP-TO-DATE
> >     :prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2531Library UP-TO-DATE
> >     :prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72531Library UP-TO-DATE
> >     :prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2531Library UP-TO-DATE
> >     :prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2531Library UP-TO-DATE
> >     :prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2531Library UP-TO-DATE
> >     :prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2531Library UP-TO-DATE
> >     :prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2531Library UP-TO-DATE
> >     :prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42531Library UP-TO-DATE
> >     :prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2531Library UP-TO-DATE
> >     :prepareComAndroidSupportTransition2531Library UP-TO-DATE
> >     :prepareCommon20171222DevReleaseLibrary UP-TO-DATE
> >     :prepareData20171222DevReleaseLibrary UP-TO-DATE
> >     :prepareList20171222DevReleaseLibrary UP-TO-DATE
> >     :prepareNetGotevUploadservice303Library UP-TO-DATE
> >     :preparePrimitives20171222DevReleaseLibrary UP-TO-DATE
> >     :prepareWidgetsReleaseLibrary UP-TO-DATE
> >     :prepareF0F1F2DebugDependencies :compileF0F1F2DebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
> >     :compileF0F1F2DebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
> >     :generateF0F1F2DebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE :cleanLocalAarFiles
> >     :ensureMetadataOutDir :collectAllJars :setProperties
> >     :generateTypescriptDefinitions SKIPPED :copyTypings SKIPPED
> >     :asbg:generateInterfaceNamesList :asbg:traverseJsFiles
> >     :asbg:runAstParser UP-TO-DATE :asbg:generateBindings Exception in
> >     thread "main" java.io.IOException: File already exists. This may lead
> >     to undesired behavior. Please change the name of one of the extended
> >     classes.
> >     E:\NS-APP\sample-ImageUpload-master\platforms\android\src\main\java\com\tns\gen\net\gotev\uploadservice\UploadServiceBroadcastReceiver_ftns_modules_nativescript_background_http_background_http_l6_c79__.java
> >             at org.nativescript.staticbindinggenerator.Generator.writeBindings(Generator.java:60)
> >             at org.nativescript.staticbindinggenerator.Main.main(Main.java:15)
> >     :asbg:generateBindings FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Build file 'E:\NS-APP\sample-ImageUpload-master\platforms\android\build-tools\android-static-binding-generator\build.gradle'
>     line: 251
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':asbg:generateBindings'.
>
>   > Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 14.86 secs Command
>   E:\NS-APP\sample-ImageUpload-master\platforms\android\gradlew.bat
>   failed with exit code 1
>
> ## run android
>
> ┌────────────────────────┬─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
>   │ Usage                  │ Synopsis
>   │ │ Run on all connected   │ $ tns run android [--key-store-path  --key-store-password  --key   │ │ devices and running 
>   │ -store-alias  --key-store-alias-password ]
>   [--release] [--justlaunch]   │ │ emulators              │
>   │ │ Run on a selected      │ $ tns run android --device 
>   [--key-store-path  --key-store        │ │ connected device
>   or    │ -password  --key-store-alias 
>   --key-store-alias-password ] [- │ │ running emulator       │ -release] [--justlaunch]                                                                │ │ Start an emulator and  │ $ tns run android --emulator [] [--key-store-path  --key   │ │ run the app inside
>   it  │ -store-password  --key-store-alias 
>   --key-store-alias-password          │ │                        │ ] [--release] [--justlaunch]
>   │
>   └────────────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
>
> Runs your project on a connected Android device or in a native Android
>   emulator, if configured. This is shorthand for prepare, build and
>   deploy. While your app is running, prints the output from the
>   application in the console and watches for changes in your code. Once
>   a change is detected, it synchronizes the change with all selected
>   devices and restarts/refreshes the application.
>
> #### Options
>
> ```
> * --no-watch - If set, changes in your code will not be reflected during the execution of this command.
> * --device - Specifies a connected device/emulator on which to run the app.
> * --emulator - If set, runs the app in a native emulator for the target platform, if configured. When set, you can also set any other
> ```
>
> valid combination of emulator options as listed by $ tns help emulate
>   android.
>       * --release - If set, produces a release build. Otherwise, produces a debug build. When set, you must also specify the
>   --key-store-* options.
>       * --key-store-path - Specifies the file path to the keystore file (P12) which you want to use to code sign your APK. You can use the
>   --key-store-* options along with --release to produce a signed release build. You need to specify all --key-store-* options.
>       * --key-store-password - Provides the password for the keystore file specified with --key-store-path. You can use the --key-store-*
>   options along with --release to produce a signed release build. You
>   need to specify all --key-store-* options.
>       * --key-store-alias - Provides the alias for the keystore file specified with --key-store-path. You can use the --key-store-* options
>   along with --release to produce a signed release build. You need to
>   specify all --key-store-* options.
>       * --key-store-alias-password - Provides the password for the alias specified with --key-store-alias-password. You can use the
>   --key-store-* options along with --release to produce a signed release build. You need to specify all --key-store-* options.
>       * --justlaunch - If set, does not print the application output in the console.
>       * --clean - If set, forces rebuilding the native application.
>
> #### Attributes
>
> ```
> * <Device ID> is the index or name of the target device as listed by $ tns device android
> * <Emulator Options> is any valid combination of options as listed by $ tns help emulate android
> ```
>
> Sending exception report (press Ctrl+C to stop).....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reset your entire project by deleting **node_modules**, **platforms** and **hooks** folders and then rebuild the project with `tns build android` or `tns run android`

Answer (score 0):

You need not delete node_modules and hooks, just deleting platforms and rebuilding should be fine.

```
rm -rf platforms
tns run android
```